# Float too large also when less than textwidth

Tags: floats, memoir

I have an image of size 112×196mm and LaTeX complains saying it is too large:

```
<figs/3d_ferro.pdf, id=1306, 318.18875pt x 559.08875pt> <use figs/3d_ferro.pdf>
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 72.20679pt on input line 400.
```

I'm using `memoir` class with `a4paper,twoside` options and the output of

```
\the\textwidth
\the\textheight
\the\linewidth
```

is

> 398.33858pt
>
> 574.74557pt
>
> 398.33858pt

I don't understand why there is this warning since both the width and the height of my image are less than the page size.

Comment: Are you packaging it inside a `figure` environment?  Does it have a caption?  Or is it merely an `\includegraphics`?

Comment: The figure is suspiciously 1inch larger.

Comment: If you merely used an `\includegraphics` on a line by itself, then the paragraph indent will also come into play.  If so, try `\noindent\includegraphics{}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, it is inside a figure environment, and I just understand the problem... I totally forgot about the caption

Comment: How can I know the height of the caption?

Comment: The caption will generally be multiples of `\baselineskip` of the appropriate font size.  However, a figure environment also adds space between figure and caption, as well as above and below the whole figure.

Comment: instead of scaling to full width (I'm guessing it is a rather tall image) how about scaling `height=0.9\textheight` instead, then thre isalso room for the caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following calculates `\textheight` minus the size of the caption.  I'm not sure why the 2pt fudge factor is needed (round off error?).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\sbox0{\parbox{\textwidth}{\null\caption{\blindtext}\null}}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height={\dimexpr\textheight-\ht0-\dp0-2pt}]{example-image}\par
\box0
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```